# Disabling Triggers in Production

Tags: trigger, data-loader

I have a trigger live in production on Contact Object and I am trying to load a set of 500 records through data loader and I don't want that trigger to  fire upon the contact records I am loading into my org through Data Loader.

How do I achieve. Is that possible, if yes, how? Can you help please.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could either create a Custom Setting or a Custom Metadata Type that contains a  checkbox called runTrigger (or something like that) .  This is set to true , and you do a check at the top of the trigger code whether it should run or not.  Mine is like this:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert,before insert,after update, before update) {

// Custom setting called TriggerSetting__c  that has a boolean called ApexTrigger__c
// This is managed in the admin UI and set to True.
TriggerSetting__c mc = TriggerSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();

if(!mc.ApexTrigger__c) return;
...
...
rest of trigger code
}
```

This has though the huge caveat that you must remember after the dataload to switch it on again!  If not then you may have a wonderful time updating those records according to business rules manually

Comment: This is why I use a  hierarchy custom setting; I can turn off triggers per user or profile instead wholesale disabling.

Comment: Even then you must remember to switch it on and off again.  I'm using hierarchy settings as well and I've forgotten to switch them on again more than once :)

Comment: Instead of data loading it again a admin in production can just turn it on/off by accessing the Custom Setting or Custom Metadata record.